# Is it possible to prevent nodes from mining on a private blockchain?

Tags: mining, testnets, private-blockchain, network, mining-pools

Is it possible to prevent mining on a closed block chain, in a sense that only a set of addresses are allowed to perform transactions but are not allowed to mine?

Mining should always be done by a preselected number of nodes with known addresses.

The solution would be preferable to use pyethapp or pyethereum.

Comment: You can setup geth such that it will no discover new nodes and has a maximus set of peers, with a list of predefined static nodes (http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/network/connecting-to-the-network.html). Althought this setup will not reject invalid nodes. Together with firewall rules to drop connections from unknown locations may work for a tests.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking at a solution based on white listing; allow only transactions from a known set of addresses and discard all others. I wonder if that is possible in the python implementations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are searching for is a [permissioned blockchain](https://docs.erisindustries.com/explainers/permissioned_blockchains/). Default node clients like geth, eth or pyehtereum does not implement this kind of functionality, so you need something more complex that implements a permission layer.

Some good starting points are the [Eris platform](https://erisindustries.com/) (my preferred, I like the overall architecture and the Docker approach) or the [BlockApps STRATO platform](http://blockapps.net/), Ethereum platform *out-of-the-box* and [Microsoft Azure ready](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/consensys/blockapps-strato/).

See [this post by Vitalik Buterin](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/07/on-public-and-private-blockchains/) for more info about public and private blockchains.

Answer (score 2):

You basically can start some `geth` with and some without `--mine`.
If you really want to enforce this then you should configure the machines with privileges so that they can only start a script that mines and some who don't. Simple Sysadmin task right?

Comment: No, it is not a simple task since it violates the distributed principle of the block chain. My setup is that I have an instance on pyethapp running on a machine and one on a separate machine (these boxes have distinct network addresses) and the one that initially stores the block chain should not allow the other to mine.